# Copy files from USB flash drive to root in OpenBSD

Tags: file-copy

I have OpenBSD 5.6 installed on my notebook computer and would like to copy files from my USB flash drive to the root of the installed OS. I figured out how to mount the USB drive using these commands:

```
# mkdir /mnt/usb
# mount /dev/sd1i /mnt/usb
# cd /mnt/usb
```

How do I copy files from `/mnt/usb` to the root of the installed OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic command to copy files is `cp`. You might want to use `ls` first to get a list of files (and directories):

```
cp some_file ~/new_name
```

copies a file under `/mnt/usb` to the file `new_name` in your home directory.

If you want to copy all files ending in `.jpg` and `.JPEG` to a new directory `pictures` under your home directory, you can use e.g.:

```
mkdir ~/pictures/
cp *.jpg *.JPEG ~/pictures/
```

I recommend you keep your root directory clean, but if you have to copy things there, `/` is the path to root, so the last command would be:

```
cp *.jpg *.JPEG /
```

Comment: You wrote `copies a file under /mnt/usb to the file new_name in your home directory`. I don't understand. When I log in as root using the root password, I'll be in the *root* directory, right? There's no such thing as a *home* directory when I log in as root??

Comment: You wrote `If you want to copy all files ending in .jpg and .JPEG to a new directory pictures under your home directory`. Suppose I wish to copy all files ending in .jpg and .JPEG to the *root* directory, what command should I type?

Comment: @user66229 I advise against that (you should keep root clean), but the root directory of your disc is `/`, so `cp *.jpg *.JPEG /` would do that.

Comment: Your command `cp *.jpg *.JPEG /` assumes that I'm in `/mnt/usb` directory, right? Suppose I'm in the root directory `/`, what is the corresponding command? Is it `cp /mnt/usb/*.jpg  /`?? And can I suppose that `cp /mnt/usb/*.jpg  /` is valid for *both* Debian *and* OpenBSD?

Comment: @user66229 Yes I assume that since you provide step 4. You provide correct command (`cp /mnt/usb/*.jpg /`) and it should work on both independent of the shell you are running on either OS.